# Использование Shared Preferences

Tags: android, android-sdk

Как записать значение в `SharedPreferences`, если у меня есть `.setText` в перезаписанном методе `onClick`? Вот часть кода:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSettings.edit();
    //editor.putString(APP_PREFERENCES_COUNTER, ); - интересует эта строка
    editor.commit();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    TextView tv = new TextView(getBaseContext());

    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.beye:
            tv.setText("...");
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
String SAVED_TEXT="sharedPref";
```

Запись

```
void saveText() {
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor ed = sPref.edit();
    ed.putString(SAVED_TEXT, etText.getText().toString());
    ed.commit();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Text saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Чтение

```
void loadText() {
    sPref = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String savedText = sPref.getString(SAVED_TEXT, "");
    etText.setText(savedText);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Text loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Comment: Вы бы пояснили, что `SAVED_TEXT` это строка-ключ, а то ТС может запутаться)

Comment: @xTIGRx Да, спасибо, но это не подходит, у меня создается новый 'TextView', а я не могу его перевести в 'String'. Меня интересует можно ли это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас есть возможность, вы можете использовать библиотеку https://github.com/martino2k6/StoreBox

Сохранение настроек будет выглядеть примерно вот так:

```
preferences.setUserName("Example User");
```

А загрузка в нужном месте вот так:

```
String userName = preferences.getUserName();
```